# Redirecting the perl script

Tags: perl

```
    print button(
      -name =>'GOOD',
      -value    =>'GOOD',
      -onclick=>'redirect_GMM()'
    );

    sub redirect_GMM()
      {
         print redirect(-url=>'http://localhost/cgi-bin/GMW/GMM.pl');
      }
```

i want to redirect the page by click the button using the onclick in the perl.

```
      print "User name:\t";

        print $q->textfield(
              -name => 'UserName',
               -value =>'Google',
               -size  => 15,
               -maxlength =>25,
            ); 
             my $uName = $q->param('UserName');
             print "<script>alert($uName)</script>";
```

not getting the value of the textfield.

Comment: You have been asking rather a lot of really basic (and really badly-framed) CGI questions over the last day or so. Can I suggest that you go off and read a good Perl/CGI tutorial for a few days. Ovid's CGI course is very good - http://ovid-cgi-course.perl-begin.org/cgi-course/

Comment: To add to what Dave Cross said, you have not accepted any answers to your previous questions. If you accept answers that help you solve your problem, you might find people are more willing to donate their time to you (no guarantees, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
      Using the javascript in Perl we can redirect the page from perl file to the another perl file

       Step 1  use CGI qw(:standard);

       Step 2   my $JSCRIPT=<<EOF;

                function redirect_GMM()
                {
                window.location.href = 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/GMW/GMM.pl';
                }   
                EOF
                 ;  
       Step 3  my $q =CGI->new;
               print $q->header('text/html');
               print $q->start_html(-title=>'JJ',-script=>$JSCRIPT);
               print $q->h5('JJ login page');
               print $q->end_html; 

       Step 4   print button(
                         -name =>'GOOD',
                         -value    =>'GOOD',
                         -onclick=>'redirect_GMM()'
                          );

         This code will surely redirect the page when you press the button.
```